# Does CloudKit support cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform, cloudkit

Just looking online and i can't seems to find a clear answer as to whether cloudkit offers cloud code? (Server side code)

I'm currently in the process of migrating my app from Parse and was looking at CloudKit as a suitable replacement. It seems like it offers data management, offers queries and a dashboard to manage all of my data but the one thing i can't seem to find any clarity as to whether this service offers the same functionality as Parse in terms of cloud code where your able to deploy your JS code to the server and call the function to return a value.

I just wanted to make sure this is possible before committing to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only create subscriptions, or you have to make your own backend and communicate with CloudKit using the web api (using server to server settings)

Comment: That's a shame since it looked pretty promising, hope they implement this in the future.